# SQL, finding most recent entry in conversation between two people

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table, Messages, which is set out as follows:

[image]

This table stores all messages sent between people, however it needs to be like FaceBook's message system.

To do this my query would need to be something like:

SELECT * FROM Messages WHERE To_User = x OR From_User = x ORDER BY Time DESC

This would fetch me every message 'x' either sent or received in order of time, newest ones appearing first.

However Facebook's system keeps it sort of like a forum, so I only want one message where person y is involved in any given query result. So I don't want this to happen:

To_User: 6
From_User: 7
Status: I agree with your message
Time: 12345

To_User: 7
To_User: 6
Status: Do you agree with my message?
Time: 12344

Say I was displaying the messages page for user 6, both messages would show up with my current system.
Instead, only the top one should be selected, because I only want to display the most recent message between user 6 and 7, rather than every one.

Naturally this would usually just ask for a LIMIT statement but I need to be able to get a lot of messages, but the only rule is that:

1- It needs to be either FROM or TO user X
2- No two messages must be selected which are FROM or TO user Y
3- The messages selected must be the NEWEST in the conversation between user X and Y

This is really hard to describe but I hope I've described it in enough detail for a solution.

I've considered doing GROUP BY but I couldn't get it to take into account that it needed to find one that was either FROM or TO me rather than just only to or only from.

If the question isn't described in enough detail, please tell me before down-voting and I'll do my best to make it a bit more detailed, but I can't think of words to describe what needs to be displayed clearly enough.

Edit:

Here's a big example of the desired feature:

Say I sent a message to John Doe, and went on my messages page straight after, at the very top it'll say

"To John Doe"
"The message I sent"

However if John Doe replies, that entry will not display on the page anymore, it'll be replaced by the newest entry in the conversation between me and John Doe, so while the actual entry is still in the database, it isn't shown anymore:

"From John Doe"
"Your message is interesting"

But if I sent one to Jane Doe afterwards, it'd push me and John Doe's conversation so it looks like this:

"To Jane Doe"
"Hello there"

"From John Doe"
"Your message is interesting"

Now with the first query I stated in this post, the result would be:

"To Jane Doe"
"Hello there"

"From John Doe"
"Your message is interesting"

"To John Doe"
"The Message I sent"

However I don't want to display more than one which is between me and John Doe, but since I'm looking at two different columns in the table (From and two) to dictate whether both I and John Doe are related, I don't think a regular GROUP BY statement would work.

Now, if in addition, Bob Joe sent me a message, it might look like:

"From Bob Joe"
"Hello"

"To Jane Doe"
"Hello there"

"From John Doe"
"Your message is interesting"

Comment: I assume you are using MySQL, right?

Comment: I cannot understand the question. :| What's wrong with LIMIT? Can you give us a real use case example?

Comment: I *think*  I understand the question, but I agree with Cranio. It would be 17 times easier to understand your question if you gave an actual example of what you are trying to do. Example input, expected output. Maybe even make a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for us.

Comment: I'll give an example, give me a moment to edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can self-join the table and use an outer join, so that any "earlier" messages will "filter out" any "non-earlier" messages.

```
SELECT * FROM Messages main LEFT JOIN Messages earlier
    ON earlier.time < main.time AND 
        (
            earlier.To_User = main.To_User AND earlier.From_User = main.From_User OR  
            earlier.To_User = main.From_User AND earlier.From_User = main.To_User
        )
WHERE (main.To_User = x OR main.From_User = x) AND earlier.id IS NULL
ORDER BY main.Time DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out now, and accept if it works, it looks like it will

Comment: Sorry, I this doesn't return anything, I've changed x to a valid ID (That has messages) and corrected the uncapitalised t in Time (I'm not sure if capitalisation matters though). Any idea why?

Comment: @AshleyDavies - I don't see much room for this not working.  What's your db engine?  If you remove the check for `earlier.id IS NULL`, what data do you see?  Are you using the exact same query, or embedding it in something larger?  How do you supply `x`?

Comment: I removed x and put in a hard-coded ID (34, which has sent two messages and received one, all relevant to a single other person, ID 1), and removed earlier.id IS NULL and still get nothing, although I might just be processing the output a bit wrong, let me just double-check.

Comment: Well I think it's working but something strange is happening, when I run: `while ($message1 = mysql_fetch_object($messages));
{
 echo "Message";
 print_r($message1);
}` I get the output : "Message", it doesn't give anything else.

Comment: @AshleyDavies - column names in mysql are not case sensitive, but table names, on some operating systems, could be.  Regarding the PHP issue, I think it will help if you replace `*` by `main.*` in the query.  Maybe you will even have to be printing specific columns in PHP.

Comment: @AshleyDavies - Here is another way around this: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-420807.html

Comment: I'm currently new to the project I'm working on right now, and it looks I was not using their MySQL library right (Although it seems more like some-thing's wrong with the library) and now I've got it working, but it's giving me the newest message three times, second newest twice, and the two oldest once each.

Comment: @AshleyDavies - because you forgot to put `earlier.id IS NULL` back in.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I added it back in and it gave me the oldest one, but I switched the lessthan into a morethan and it seems to work now, I'll just put a few tests in and if it works accept the answer. Thanks a lot for helping though, I wish I could give multiple upvotes. :(

Comment: @AshleyDavies One upvote is quite enough, and if you want to help others, you can edit the question heading to say "latest" instead of "earliest" if that is what you meant, or otherwise make it a good reference point.  (I have already tagged it with mysql but did not otherwise edit it.)  Thank you.

Comment: Oh, I changed my aims during the question and forgot to change title. Sorry about that, fixed now. Thank you for helping though, I was beginning to think that this was unachievable without having a separate table to keep track over conversations or another ugly workaround.

Answer (score 1):

If you could eliminate the complication of a person appearing in either the "from" or "to" columns, then this would be an instance of the common problem of finding the minimum row within a group.  So you could start with this:

```
SELECT id, time, to_user as user
UNION ALL SELECT id, time, from_user as user
```

and then use the results of that query as the input to any of the standard [minimum row techniques](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/db2luw/finding-the-maximum-row-efficiently-12948).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get rid of them being in either one or the other, I need to keep track so I know who sent the individual message

Comment: I don't mean change your original table structure; I mean use the results of that `SELECT` query as the input for a minimum-row technique.

Comment: Ah, misunderstood your answer, sorry.